# Insert data through a script directly in the db

Tags: html, wpdb, scripts

is it possible to insert data through a script or HTML site into the wpdb and this will show up as normal article in the, the same as when I use the 'create new post' page?

Which tables are affected or should I care about?

BR,
mybecks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes its possible but why go over the trouble when you can use the native functions like [wp_insert_post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post)  that will take care of the interaction with the database.

If you are still looking to do it directly by `$wpdb` then the post data is saved in the posts table, the meta data for posts is saved in the postmeta table.

Comment: actually I use a plugin 'Custom Field Template'. With this I can attach extra information to a post. This don't work in a mobile browser. So I think about to develop a mobile page which has the same imput fields as my Custom Field Template and Post.